# Unable to find elements by class name using Selenium/Python 2.7

Tags: python, selenium, google-translate

I'm trying to select all available languages from the google translate "detect language" dropdown so that I can automate some translations.

I don't get any syntax errors, but the "find_elements_by_class_name" method (that I supposed would get all languages) comes up empty.

```
from selenium import webdriver
fire = webdriver.Firefox()
fire.get("http://translate.google.com")
sl_dropdown = fire.find_element_by_id("gt-sl-gms")  # dropdown menu
# returns empty list
sl_dropdown.find_elements_by_class_name("goog-menuitem-content")
```

I'm just starting out with Selenium so I'm sure there's something I'm missing.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why did you expect to find any `'goog-menuitem-content'` elements? I don't see any when inspecting the page.

Comment: @jonrsharpe After clicking the dropdown and clicking "inspect element"  'goog-menuitem-content' is the class name for any given language, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues.

One thing since you are new to Selenium... Selenium will only interact with elements that the user can see. So, you can't get a list of languages from the dropdown if the dropdown is not open exposing the elements. To fix that, just add a click before pulling the elements by class name.

The other issue is that the elements containing the language names are not children of the `DIV` with id = "gt-sl-gms". If you look at the HTML, the menu with the langs is all down lower in the HTML. So you will need to adjust your search to not look for just children of `sl_dropdown`.

I don't know python but hopefully this is correct and/or can set you in the right direction.

```
from selenium import webdriver
fire = webdriver.Firefox()
fire.get("http://translate.google.com")
sl_dropdown = fire.find_element_by_id("gt-sl-gms")  # dropdown menu
sl_dropdown.click() # opens the languages menu so its accessible to Selenium
langs = fire.find_elements_by_css_selector("#gt-sl-gms-menu div.goog-menuitem-content")
for lang in langs:
    print lang.text  # dumps the text in each WebElement
```

BTW, the CSS Selector `#gt-sl-gms-menu div.goog-menuitem-content` means get an element with an id (#) of gt-sl-gms-menu that has a descendant DIV with the class (.) goog-menuitem-content. Hopefully that makes sense. There are a lot of good tutorials on the web for CSS selectors. I use [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) as a reference a LOT.

---

EDIT 1:
This is the code I used in Java to dump the languages.

```
driver.get("http://translate.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("gt-sl-gms")).click();
List<WebElement> langs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#gt-sl-gms-menu div.goog-menuitem-content"));
for (WebElement lang : langs)
{
    System.out.println(lang.getText());
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you.  But this returns a list of webelement objects and I'm not sure how to get the text of them.  lang.text returns "u''" for each object, and get_element("value") gives me something similarly unintended.

Comment: I don't know python but if you loop through all instances of langs and dump langs.text it should print the languages... at least it does in Java. I'm not sure why it would be different. I added the working code in Java in case it helps you or someone else.

Comment: Updated based on a suggested revision by @NoSuchElephantException that was rejected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machine. If I call `click()` afterwards, the dropdown list of languages opens:

```
from selenium import webdriver
fire = webdriver.Firefox()
fire.get("http://translate.google.com")
sl_dropdown = fire.find_element_by_id("gt-sl-gms")  # dropdown menu
sl_dropdown.click()
```

I use Python 2.7.6, Selenium 2.47.1

Comment: I'm not just trying to get the dropdown (should have made that clearer).  I'm trying to select the individual languages, ie come up with a list like ["Albanian", "Armenian"]